# Poco C++ SAX parser: how to get element "inner text"?

Tags: c++, poco, sax

I've been going over the Poco SAX parser header files a few times but I can't seem to find any info on how to obtain an element's inner text. For example:

```
<description>This is the inner text.</description>
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, found the solution myself. I needed to use implement the 'characters' method like this:

```
void MyParser::characters(const Poco::XML::XMLChar ch[], int start, int length)
{
  std::string innerText = std::string(ch + start, length);
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Looking into Poco XML parsing.